# Finding an initial value in an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

Given an ODE, $y'(t) = f(t, y), t \in [a, b], y(a) = \alpha$, and a value I, find an $\alpha \in R$ so that the solution satisfies $\int_{a}^{b}y(t)dt = I$.

Can someone explain to me what techniques I should use.  You needn't go into too much detail.

Comment: Can you get the general solution analytically? Or is this a numerics problem? The tags make it sound that way but the body doesn't.

Comment: $y'(t) = f(t, y)$ can be found numerically, but there is no analytic expression.

Comment: How can anyone know which techniques you've studied that would apply here.  Please add context to improve your question.  As it is, it is too vague what your knowledge base is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming from the tags that this is a numerics problem, you can view $\alpha \mapsto \int_a^b y(t) dt-I$ as an expensive-to-evaluate black box function (which you could implement numerically by using an ODE solver together with a numerical integrator), and then use scalar root finders on it.

A more elegant way to do it is to look at $Y(t)=\int_a^t y(s) ds$. Notice that regardless of the value of $\alpha$ you have $Y''=f(t,Y'),Y(a)=0$, and that if $\alpha$ is selected correctly then $Y(b)=I$. So you can solve that second order BVP using any of various solvers for second order BVPs, and then extract $Y'(0)$ from your representation of the solution. The method of the previous paragraph is equivalent to the shooting method for this BVP.